# Cпецификатора final. Не происходит ошибки времени компиляции

Tags: c++

Хочу запретить возможность переопределять метод базового класса с помощу спецификатора final и вызвать ошибку времени компиляции. Но дочерний класс переопределяеть базовый метод.

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    virtual void show() = 0;
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    virtual void show() override final
    {
        std::cout<<"B"<<std::endl;
    };
};

class C : public A
{
public:
virtual void show() override
    {
        std::cout<<"C"<<std::endl;
    };  
};

int main (int argc, char const* argv[])
{

    A *a = new B;
    a->show();
    A *a2 = new C;
    a2->show(); // нет ошибки

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Собственно а у вас и не должно быть там ошибки. Вынаследуете `С` от `А`, а в `А` не указан спецификатор `final`. Если бы вы наследовали от `B`, тогда была бы ошибка, а так все нормально.

Comment: @Flowneee может ответом оформите?

Answer (score 2):

Собственно у вас и не должно быть там ошибки. Вынаследуете `С` от `А`, а в `А` не указан спецификатор `final`. Если бы вы наследовали от `B`, тогда была бы ошибка, а так все нормально.